# Should Debian's backup account be used?

Tags: debian, users, backup

Linux distributions contain several system user accounts such as `daemon`, `bin`, `sys`, etc.  Debian includes an account for `backup`.

Is it alright to actually use this account?  That is, give the account the ability to login via SSH so that it can do backups.  I have done this and it works fine, but I am wondering if there is a reason this should not be done.

Comment: There is some information https://askubuntu.com/questions/63685/what-is-the-default-backup-user-for

Comment: @AlexD Thank you.  That link kind of answers the question, but not fully.  The Debian documentation quoted seems to ask if what it is saying is correct.  I checked and even over 10 years latter the documentation is unchanged.  There is no reason given for why these things are recommended and I was hoping for more insight about that.

Answer (score 5):

The `backup` user is used by two backup programs in Debian, [AMANDA](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/amanda) and [Cedar Backup](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/cedar-backup3). The [`amanda-server` `README.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/amanda/-/blob/master/debian/amanda-server.README.Debian) gives details, and in particular it instructs users to change the `backup` user’s login shell and set up SSH keys for it.

If `amanda-server` uses the `backup` user in this fashion, I suspect that your usage is fine. There is one possible area for concern, the use of `/var/backups` as the `backup` user’s home directory; the issue [was raised on the `debian-devel` mailing list back in 2000](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2000/01/msg00175.html) but didn’t get any attention. (See also two discussions on `/var/backups`, from [2002](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2002/08/msg00150.html) and [2004](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2004/10/msg01472.html).)

Comment: Thanks for the well-researched answer. I've always wondered about this and now I know!

Answer (score 2):

The `backup` user has logins disabled by having its shell as `/usr/sbin/nologin`, and its home directory is `/var/backups`... which does not seem to be empty.

If you run `sudo grep -r var/backups /etc`, you'll find a number of daily cron jobs that back up certain "essential" data to `/var/backups`:

- package `dpkg` includes `/etc/cron.daily/dpkg` which maintains several rolling copies of the package manager state. Since `dpkg` is the low-level package manager, it is probably present in practically all installations of Debian.
- the optional TUI package management tool `aptitude` does the same for its extra state information, with `/etc/cron.daily/aptitude`.
- if you have `samba` installed, it saves a backup of `/etc/samba/smbpasswd` if it exists, to `/var/backups/smbpasswd.bak`.
- if you have the OpenLDAP server `slapd` installed, it seems to also back up its schema under `/var/backups/slapd-<package version number>`.

In many cases, there seems to be 7 copies of each state file stored, similar to how `logrotate` keeps a rotating archive of past log files.

So it seems that there is (or was) a poorly-documented idea to collect daily copies of essential system metadata to `/var/backups`, and some packets are implementing it, while others aren't.

So at the very least, if you plan to use the `backup` user account for your own purposes, be aware that at least its default home directory `/var/backups` is likely to have a number of (small) extra files dumped to it daily. All the cron scripts I found so far have specified the directory explicitly as `/var/backups`, so if you change the user's home directory to something else, you most likely would escape the deluge.

Comment: Note, however, that none of these cron daily scripts use the `backup` _user_ (or group), and all files at `/var/backups`, including that directory itself, are owned by `root:root`. So I believe `/var/backups` is mostly unrelated to the `backup` user

Comment: As I said, the default home directory of the `backup` user is defined as `/var/backups`. My answer was mostly just a warning that if you want to use the user account, you should change its home directory to something else to avoid surprises.